# Higcharts: how to remove the styles of the tooltip container?

Tags: highcharts

I have the [following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delux123/5mcq1d3s/2/), where I am trying to move the values (for the hover points) in a static position at the top-left of the chart.

Here are my settings, related to the tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  borderRadius: 10,
  formatter: function () {
    return this.points.reduce(function (s, point) {
      let tooltipTxt = "";
      tooltipTxt += point.x + "<br/>";
      tooltipTxt += "Price: " + point.y + "<br/>";
      return tooltipTxt;
    }, this.x);
  },
  outside: true,
  borderWidth: 0,
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  shadow: false,
  style: {
    color: '#000'
  },
  useHTML: true,
  hideDelay: 3600000,
  positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
    return {
        x: 30,
        y: 0
    };
 },
},
```

How can I remove the styling of the box at the top-right and to remove the lines that connect this box, with the current mouse position?
For example, I tried to illustrate this, by scratching the lines that I want to remove (additionally the backwound of the tooltip box should be transparent)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the styled mode, so you need to remove the border by CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip-box {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3L6t0d2e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.styledMode

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

Comment: And how can I set the background color of the tooltip to be transparent? I cannot find the proper class while inspecting the elements. Can you please update your answer with that as well?

Comment: adding `.highcharts-tooltip-box .highcharts-label-box { fill: transparent; }` fixed the background color as well